# 'reference to setCapability is ambiguous' on Appium Java project for Android Caps

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am working on Appium-Java maven driven framework and getting below error for Android Capabilities

> reference to setCapability is ambiguous
>
> [ERROR]   both method
> setCapability(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) in
> org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities and method
> setCapability(java.lang.String,org.openqa.selenium.Platform) in
> org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities match

Versions:

```
Selenium Version:<selenium.java.version>3.11.0</selenium.java.version> [Also tried with 3.141.59, 3.12.0, 3.7.1]
And Appium version:
<appium.java-client.version>6.1.0</appium.java-client.version>
```

Code Snippet:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$." + "platformName"));
```

Comment: return type of  `JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$." + "platformName")` should be a Java `String` type

Comment: Surprisingly, same test ran all fine when triggered using standalong Cucumber-runner. but keep failing when used 'mvn clean test'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecasting Output from `JsonPath.read` , to String resolved the issue.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", (String) JsonPath.read(jsonFile, "$." + "platformName"));
```